# Flutter Pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build my flutter iOS App but I don't know how to get the ipa file.

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands: xcode

steps:
- task: aloisdeniel.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
  displayName: 'Flutter Install'

- task: aloisdeniel.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0
  displayName: 'Flutter Build ios'
  inputs:
    target: ios
    projectDirectory: 'src/Apps/platypus_app'
    buildName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    entryPoint: 'lib/main_staging.dart'
    iosCodesign: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'src/Apps/platypus_app/build/ios'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'ZooKeeper_Certs.p12'
    certPwd: ZooK33periOSKeyStore

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    artifact: 'platypus_drop'
```

This pipeline builds but I get the following output:

[image]

There is no .ipa file so I think there is another step I have to do, but I am no iOS dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need [xCode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) to generate .ipa file. See document [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive).

Add Xcode task after flutter task in your pipeline. Set the `packageApp` attribute to `true`. Set the  `exportPath` attribute. **The path you set for `exportPath` attribute is where the .ipa will be generated.** See below example:

```
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive' 
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: default, 10, 9, 8, specifyPath
    archivePath: 'src/Apps/platypus_app/build/ios/Runner.xcarchive'
    exportPath: 'src/Apps/platypus_app/build/ios'
    packageApp: true
    xcWorkspacePath: src/Apps/platypus_app/build/ios/Runner.xcworkspace
    signingOption: 'nosign'
```

Another workaround is to use a bash task to run `xcodebuild` command to generate .ipa file in your pipeline. See below example:

**The .ipa file will be exported to the folder specified for `-exportPath` attribute**

```
- task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Create ipa package'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        xcodebuild -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme prod -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release-prod archive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive
        xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build/ios/Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ci/ExportOptions.plist -exportPath build/ios/App.ipa
```

Please check out [this thread](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/vsts-flutter-tasks/issues/28) for more information.

Comment: I used the Xcode Task and it worked quiet fine, though it is very confusing with the schemes etc. My pipeline now generates an ipa which I can deploy to some testers, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `ExportOptions.plist` file with `flutter build ipa` and you will get an ipa output in `build/ios/ipa/your_app.ipa`

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: "Build flutter iOS release"
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      flutter build ipa --release --build-name=1.0 --build-number 1 --export-options-plist=path/to/exportOptions.plist
```

Read here for more details:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive