# Azure DevOps Flutter CI/CD pipeline for iOS and watchOS app fails to publish to TestFlight

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-devops, watchos

I have an existing Azure DevOps pipeline to build the Flutter iOS app. This app includes the Watch app and Watch app extension.

I use manual signing with an Apple Distribution certificate (.p12), and three .mobileprovision profiles (for the main app, watchkit, and watchkit extension).

The build pipeline builds an IPA file and starts to upload the file to the TestFlight using Fastlane.

Here we get the error:

```
Error: Asset validation failed Invalid Code Signature Identifier. The identifier "com.apple.WK" in your code signature for "App" must match its Bundle Identifier "com.org.app.watchkitapp"
```

Here is a pipeline code:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: iOSStage
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macos-latest'
    dependsOn: []
    displayName: iOS
    jobs:

      - job: iOSJob
        displayName: iOS
        variables:
          FLUTTER_XCODE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: ""
          FLUTTER_XCODE_CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED: NO
          FLUTTER_XCODE_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED: NO
        steps:
          - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
            displayName: Install main app provisioning profile
            inputs:
              provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
              provProfileSecureFile: 'baseapp_provisioning.mobileprovision'

          # Install WatchKit extension provisioning profile
          - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
            displayName: Install WatchKit extension provisioning profile
            inputs:
              provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
              provProfileSecureFile: 'watchkitapp_provisioning.mobileprovision'

          # Install WatchKit app provisioning profile
          - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
            displayName: Install WatchKit app provisioning profile
            inputs:
              provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
              provProfileSecureFile: 'watchkitextension_provisioning.mobileprovision'


          # replace "iosKey" and "yourPwd" with your secure file name and password
          - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
            displayName: Install certificate
            inputs:
              certSecureFile: 'apple_distribution.p12'
              certPwd: '$(PASS)'
              keychain: 'temp'
              setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: true

          - task: FlutterInstall@0
            displayName: "Install Flutter SDK"
            inputs:
              mode: 'auto'
              channel: 'stable'
              version: 'latest'

          - task: FlutterCommand@0
            displayName: "Run Flutter diagnostics"
            inputs:
              projectDirectory: '.'
              arguments: 'doctor -v'

          - script: |
              gem install cocoapods

          # adjust path to the *.plist file
          - task: FlutterBuild@0
            displayName: "Build application"
            inputs:
              target: ipa
              projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              buildName: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
              exportOptionsPlist: 'ios/ExportOptions.plist'
              debugMode: false
              profileMode: false
              verboseMode: true
              
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            displayName: "Copy app to staging directory"
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
              contents: '**/ipa/*.ipa'
              targetFolder: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)'
              flattenFolders: true

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: "Publish IPA file"
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'IPA'
              publishLocation: 'Container'

          - task: AppStoreRelease@1
            displayName: "Publish to the App Store TestFlight track"
            inputs:
              authType: 'ApiKey'
              apiKeyId: 'some-key-id'
              apiKeyIssuerId: 'some-issuer-id'
              apitoken: 'base64-api-token'
              releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
              appIdentifier: 'com.org.app'
              appType: 'iOS'
              ipaPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.ipa'
              shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
              shouldSkipSubmission: true
              appSpecificId: '1234'
              teamId: 'some-id'
              teamName: 'my-team'
            enabled: true
            timeoutInMinutes: 30
            retryCountOnTaskFailure: 1
```

And the ExportOptions.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/> <!-- Adjust based on your preference -->
    <key>uploadBitcode</key>
    <false/> <!-- Adjust based on your preference -->
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <false/> <!-- Adjust based on your preference -->
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>SOME-TEAM-ID</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>Apple Distribution: ORG (ORG_ID)</string> <!-- Replace with your certificate name -->
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.org.app</key>
        <string>baseapp_provisioning</string> <!-- Replace with your provisioning profile name -->
        <key>com.org.app.watchkitapp</key>
        <string>watchkitapp_provisioning</string> <!-- Replace with your provisioning profile name -->
        <key>com.org.app.watchkitapp.watchkitextension</key>
        <string>watchkitextension_provisioning</string> <!-- Replace with your provisioning profile name -->
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm stuck on this error for several days and don't have an idea where else to look for solution.

I tried to generate different types of certificate (.p12) and .mobileprovision profiles. I tried different flags for signing in the pipeline, but I can't get past this error.

I suppose the problem is either with iOS (watchOS) settings, ExportOptions, DevOps build pipeline, or certificates.

If everything would work this pipeline should publish IPA file to the TestFlight.

UPDATE:

I investigated further and based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664300) forum thread as user @[wade zhou - MSFT suggested], I ran these two commands for my iOS app, watchOS app, and watchOS extension:

```
$ codesign -d -v My-App.app 
... Identifier=com.myorg.My-App ...

$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :CFBundleIdentifier" 
My-App.app/Info.plist com.myorg.My-App
```

And got these results:

```
iOS app:
codesign: Identifier=com.myorg.My-App
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App

watchOS app:
codesign: Identifier=com.apple.WK
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp

watchOS extension:
codesign: Identifier=com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
```

So the signature of the watchOS app is not right and does not match the one in Info.plist of the watchOS app. I still don't know why.

Comment: Maybe you can download the ipa file from build artifact, unpack the .ipa, check code signing identifier and bundle ID. Please refer to the [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664300) for the details.

Comment: I checked like in the link you provided @wadezhou-MSFT and these are the results:
iOS app:
codesign: Identifier=com.myorg.My-App
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App | 
watchOS app:
codesign: Identifier=com.apple.WK
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp | 
 watchOS extension:
codesign: Identifier=com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp.watchkitextension
PlistBuddy: com.myorg.My-App.watchkitapp.watchkitextension | 

My conclusion: iOS app and watchOS extension match, but it looks like the problem is in the signature of watchkitapp? Where could be the reason for this?

Comment: Instead of task `FlutterBuild@0`, what if you use `flutter build ipa ... --export-options-plist=path/to/exportOptions.plis` command to create the ipa? Check if it has correct signature. Please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67370702/14996050)